# OnBeforeWebRequest sometimes returns details object with tabId= -1. Filter is "main_page" what does this request mean?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know the documentation says that -1 indicates that it is not related to a tab. However, I am confused because my filtering is set to main_page navigations, which I would think is always associated with a tab? What type of request would generated this.

Pardon my noob question.

Comment: Note: to be certain, I directly cancelled these request. The tab at which the navigation began on was updated to a "blocked by extension" page. so not sure why its not consider associated with the tab.

Comment: Edit: The api is chrome.webrequest.onBeforeRequest.

Comment: Might be a hidden pre-rendered tab. It'll be shown a bit later to the user if the navigation isn't cancelled and only then it gets a real tab id.

Comment: I had thought about that as well, however pre-rendered tabs are typically normal tab id's its just that the tabs dont exist. So i think this might be something different.

Comment: Try to find what's different about that request. Try to isolate the sequence to reproduce it. Maybe that URL is an internal Google service.